# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'importStylesheet' on 'XSLTProcessor': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, xslt

I am trying to use XSL to translate an XML file into a neat table. For that I used the examples provided by W3schools which can be located [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp) as a starting point. Yet the browser(chrome) is throwing the error that is described in the title of this post. I even tried copying the exact same example on W3 only to be met with the same error. Tried debugging in Firefox, this is the console output
`TypeError: Argument 1 of XSLTProcessor.importStylesheet is not an object.`

A similar question was posted before and the solution was in changing the model from synchronous to async. I tried doing that through the onreadystatechange method but without success. Here is the code I worked with.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function loadXMLDoc(filename)
    {
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
      {
      xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }
    else
      {
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        return xhttp.responseXML;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", filename);
    try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
    xhttp.send("");
    }

    function displayResult()
    {
    xsl = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xsl");
    xml = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xml");
    // code for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
      {
      ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
      document.getElementById("dataTable").innerHTML = ex;
      }
    // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
      {
      xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
      xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
      resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
      document.getElementById("dataTable").appendChild(resultDocument);
      }
    }   
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="dataTable" />
</body>
```

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: If you want to use asynchronous XMLHttpRequest then you need to put the code processing and using the `responseXML` into the event handler or at least call it from the event handler.

Comment: No, use synchronous loading (`xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);`) as done in the example you have linked to or make sure you use the `onreadystatehandler` to deal with the responseXML.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Martin. Based on your comment I wrote this code
      `xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {
     return xhr.responseXML;
    }
   }
   xhr.open("GET", fileName);
   xhr.send("");`
I re-factored the code to use the sync model but without the event handlers and it worked. Yet the opposite is not true, to use the async model but with event handlers. The code above is my attempt at that. My appologies for the formatting, I tried many times to block format it and it didn't work.

Comment: You can't return something from an event handler, you have to call your code supposed to be executed once you have an `responseXML`. So a simple approach would be to load one XML asynchronously, in its onreadystatechnage call code to load the second and in that second onreadystatehandler to call the code to do the transformation and insert the transformation result. You will need to make sure you pass the data received on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of two asynchronous requests where the callback of one event handler starts the next request whose callback does the transformation. To keep it simple, I have used `onload` instead of `onreadystatechange`, if you really need support for old IE versions you will need to adapt the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>XMLHttpRequest and onload handler with asynchronous requests</title>
<script>
function load(url, callback) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', url);
  // to allow us doing XSLT in IE
  try { req.responseType = "msxml-document" } catch (ex) {}
  req.onload = function() {
    callback(req.responseXML);
  };
  req.send();
}

function transform(xml, xsl) {
  load(
    xml,
    function(inputXml) {
      load(
        xsl,
        function(xsltSheet) {
          displayResult(inputXml, xsltSheet);
        }
      );
    }
  );
}

function displayResult(xmlInput, xsltSheet) {
  if (typeof XSLTProcessor !== 'undefined') {
    var proc = new XSLTProcessor();
    proc.importStylesheet(xsltSheet);
    document.getElementById('example').appendChild(proc.transformToFragment(xmlInput, document));
  }
  else if (typeof xmlInput.transformNode !== 'undefined') {
    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = xmlInput.transformNode(xsltSheet);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
  <body onload="transform('catalog.xml', 'catalog.xsl')">
<div id="example"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Online at http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015072001.html, works fine with current versions of IE, Firefox and Chrome on Windows 8.1.

If you want to start two asynchronous requests directly to load XML and XSLT then you need to do some more work to make sure you know when both documents have been loaded to process them, an example of that is at http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015072101.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>XMLHttpRequest and onload handler with asynchronous requests</title>
<script>
function makeRequest(url, loadedData, property, elementToAddResult) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', url);
  // to allow us doing XSLT in IE
  try { req.responseType = "msxml-document" } catch (ex) {}
  req.onload = function() {
    loadedData[property] = req.responseXML;
    if (checkLoaded(loadedData)) {
      displayResult(loadedData.xmlInput, loadedData.xsltSheet, elementToAddResult);
    };
  };
  req.send();
}  

function checkLoaded(loadedData) {
  return loadedData.xmlInput != null && loadedData.xsltSheet != null;
}

function loadAndTransform(xml, xsl, elementToAddResult) {
  var loadedData = { xmlInput: null, xsltSheet: null };

  makeRequest(xml, loadedData, 'xmlInput', elementToAddResult);
  makeRequest(xsl, loadedData, 'xsltSheet', elementToAddResult);
}  

function displayResult(xmlInput, xsltSheet, elementToAddResult) {
  if (typeof XSLTProcessor !== 'undefined') {
    var proc = new XSLTProcessor();
    proc.importStylesheet(xsltSheet);
    elementToAddResult.appendChild(proc.transformToFragment(xmlInput, document));
  }
  else if (typeof xmlInput.transformNode !== 'undefined') {
    elementToAddResult.innerHTML = xmlInput.transformNode(xsltSheet);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
  <body onload="loadAndTransform('catalog.xml', 'catalog.xsl', document.getElementById('example'));">
<div id="example"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Martin very much. I'm still digesting the information you have provided. More so the concept of callbacks. I'm new to programming in general. I will post more questions once I understand the code you have provided. I just wanted to thank you for all the help.

Comment: There is something I found weird while working with the code. If the browser has a big cache, I would get an error `argument 1 of the XSLTP.importStylesheet is not of type "Node"`  If I clear the cache, everything works wonderfully. Is there an explanation for that? Thank you

Comment: Well any request by the browser might be loaded from its cache, whether it is a link or something done with script and `XMLHttpRequest`. And if at some point the file loaded was not even a well-formed XML document then, depending on the browser, the `responseXML` might be null.