# Failed to execute 'importStylesheet' on 'XSLTProcessor': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an XML file with an XSLT on the client.
I tried using the W3Schools method and it worked fine locally, but threw the above error when placed on my server. I checked MIME types are set btw.

I tried the approach suggested in this question, but again it only worked locally.

[Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'importStylesheet' on 'XSLTProcessor': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459664/uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-execute-importstylesheet-on-xsltprocessor-par)

I'm stuck on this and would appreciate some help. My url is:
http://tinyurl.com/hm6phwu

Answer (score 0):

I checked the response headers of the url below.

Request URL:http://s598918594.websitehome.co.uk/website//podcasts/test.xslt

The problem is with the following header

Content-Type:"text/html"

Set the Content-Type of your .xslt file as application/xml

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.I added the following to the web.config file  
 <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".xslt" mimeType="application/xml" />
    </staticContent>
I still have the same problem unfortunately

Comment: The url is still showing the Content-Type as "text/html"